# Android NDK - Loading the symbol of only the main DLL\SO from dlsym()

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Using Android NDK and with generated libraries (`.so`)

I need to get the address of a method which is present only in the main SO. Using `dlsym()` after `dlopen()` will provide the address of the method but it will search for that method in all the linked SO's. But I need to get the address of the method only if that method is part of the main SO and NOT if it's part of any other linked SO's.

For example, if I have opened `A.so` using `dlopen()` and then call `dlsym()` to check for the function `foo()`, using the handle provided by `dlopen()`, then I should get the handle only if it is part of `A.so`. currently, `dlsym()` provides the address even if `foo()` is part of `B.so` which is linked to `A.so` ( I need the `dlsym()` to search only in `A.so` and not in it's other linked or dependent libraries).

On Linux if we use `dlopen()` with the flag '`RTLD_FIRST`' the desired behavior can be achieved. But '`RTLD_FIRST`' doesn't seem to be supported in Android. I verified the '`dlfcn.h`' header file for the macro '`RTLD_FIRST`' & is not present.

If this is completely not possible in Android-NDK, then can we somehow get the name of the SO in which the method is present. In the above example if I can get that `foo()` is part of `B.so`, I can do a simple check to determine if it's from the desired library.

The code is in C language.
Can anyone please let me know how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: vote up for a good question!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who want to know how I achieved the desired results.
Since `RTLD_LOCAL` & other related flags were not providing the desired results, obtain the address of the method using `dlsym()` & pass that address to `dladdr(const void* __addr, Dl_info* __info)`. `dladdr()` returns adequate method details in `Dl_info`, at least what I wanted. The `Dl_info->dli_fname` pointer, contains the complete path of the DLL/Library in which the method was found.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym

> **RTLD_LOCAL**
>
> This is the converse of **RTLD_GLOBAL**, and the default if
> neither flag is specified. Symbols defined in this library are not
> made available to resolve references in subsequently loaded libraries.

Try to use flag `RTLD_LOCAL` in `dlopen()`.

Comment: Thanks for your time to edit the question & for your answer. The flat 'RTLD_LOCAL' still resolves the function foo() present in the second library B.so. I tried dlopen( "A.so", RTLD_LOCAL) to obtain the handle. Is there a way to obtain the library from which the method was resolved ? It will also be fine, if I get to know if foo() was from B.so

Comment: Maybe you can check the symbols type is external reference or not